# Validating an IP address using bash script

Tags: bash

I am very new to bash script so basically i can not understand it very much so please can any one suggest me ways that i can learn faster.

I am tryong to write a bash script to read ip adress and validate it.
So please can you tell me what mistaking I am making in the script that i have used.

```
function valid_ip()
{
    local  IPA1=$1
    local  stat=1

    if [[ $IPA1 =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]];
    then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        ip=($ip)
        IFS=$OIFS

        [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
           && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
        stat=$?
    fi
    return $stat
}
```

This code also i have taken from the internet itself just to understand the concept but still i cannot get it.

Comment: What parts don't you understand?

Comment: parts that is placed after then

Comment: Have you read about IFS in `man bash`?

Comment: yes i have read IFS in man bash

Comment: Use `IFS=. read -a ip <<< "$ip"`; it's shorter and less error-prone than trying to save and restore `IFS` manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read comments:

```
    function valid_ip()
{
    local  IPA1=$1
    local  stat=1

    if [[ $IPA1 =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]];
    then
        OIFS=$IFS

   IFS='.'             #read man, you will understand, this is internal field separator; which is set as '.' 
        ip=($ip)       # IP value is saved as array
        IFS=$OIFS      #setting IFS back to its original value;

        [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
           && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]  # It's testing if any part of IP is more than 255
        stat=$? #If any part of IP as tested above is more than 255 stat will have a non zero value
    fi
    return $stat # as expected returning
```

You can check the default value of IFS by `printf '%q' $IFS` before setting it to any other value.

Answer (score 1):

```
function valid_ip()
{
    local  IPA1=$1
    local  stat=1

    if [[ $IPA1 =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]];
    then
        OIFS=$IFS # Save the actual IFS in a var named OIFS
        IFS='.'   # IFS (Internal Field Separator) set to .
        ip=($ip)  # ¿Converts $ip into an array saving ip fields on it?
        IFS=$OIFS # Restore the old IFS

        [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]  # If $ip[0], $ip[1], $ip[2] and $ip[3] are minor or equal than 255 then

        stat=$? # $stat is equal to TRUE if is a valid IP or FALSE if it isn't

    fi # End if

    return $stat  # Returns $stat
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues finding a good answer to this, as well, but I finally came up with a line that properly validates if it is a real IP or not (format-wise). Change the IP to non-valid IP and see no output instead:

```
echo '255.154.12.231' | grep -E '(([0-9]{1,3})\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}){1}'  | grep -vE '25[6-9]|2[6-9][0-9]|[3-9][0-9][0-9]' | grep -Eo '(([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]){1}'
```

1st part checks for 1-3 digits from 0-9 followed by a dot. It will do it 3 times{3}then repeats without the .

2nd part gets rid of any line containing 256 to 999 in separate stages. You have to be explicit explaining the numbers; so 256-259, 260-299,300-999.
There is probably a way to make this check better with a + somewhere, as to say any number greater than X.

3rd part, was where I started and it was grepping the exact term, meaning it was taking with it undesirable characters hanging on either side of it. It is only while writing this that I realized I once again find my answer by getting rid of the impossibles, rather than looking for the possibles, so the last part is not needed. Try this:

```
echo '255.154.12.231' | grep -E '(([0-9]{1,3})\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}){1}'  | grep -vE '25[6-9]|2[6-9][0-9]|[3-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

posix shell compliant, no regexp, fast, readable, ipv4 only:

```bash
validate_ip ()
{
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo 'no ip supplied' >&2

        exit 1
    fi

    OFS=$IFS
    IFS=.

    set -- $1

    IFS=$OFS

    if [ $# -ne 4 ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    for i; do
        # not a number
        case "$i" in
            ''|*[!0-9]*)
                return 1
                ;;
        esac

        # not in range 0-255
        if [ "$i" -lt 0 -o "$i" -gt 255 ]; then
            return 1
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only checking IPv4. The easiest way to check if it's any kind of IP address (IPv4 or IPv6) is with a python one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_ADDR="::1"

if python3 -c "import ipaddress; ipaddress.ip_address('${IP_ADDR}')" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "IP_ADDR is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address"
else
    echo "IP_ADDR is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

With a Perl's one liner, with a proper parser, works both for `IPv4` and `IPv6`:

```
valid_ipv4() {
    perl -MRegexp::Common -sle '
        if ($str  /^$RE{net}{IPv4}$/) {
            exit(0)
        }
        else {
            exit(1)
        }
    ' -- -str=$1
    return $?
}
```

Just swap `IPv4` to `IPv6` if needed.